# How to send HTTP POST request to another site?

Tags: php

I am trying to send this POST request to another site, but I do not really know how to do so. Is it even possible with this code?

```
<html>
    <body>
            <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden"
                    <?php
                            echo " value='";
                            for($i=0;$i<2147483648;$i++)
                                    {
                                            echo "a";
                                    }
                            echo "'";
                    ?>
                    >
                    <input type="submit">
            </form>
<?php if(isset($_POST['test'])){
    echo $_POST['test'];
}
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

If so, how do I target the website/run this?

Comment: Something seems fishy with this code...

Answer (score 0):

You could send a POST request to another server by using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). See the example [here](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) from David Walsh.

And if you're stuck with PHP don't throw out good design - encapsulate the logic of your custom cURL code in a function so you only define and change it in a single place.

Comment: Where is the cURL download? I have been on that site before but I cannot find the download

Comment: cURL is a library and it's included in the standard PHP distributions. All you need to do is use the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have not  mentioned action in form tag. Action tells where to post the form